# How does Flutter Widget rerender works when it's properties change?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-bloc

I'm just wondering how Flutter Widget works when Parent widget's properties change.

Let's say we have a Parent Widget which renders Widget base on some mutable value or some listenable value (like in Bloc Pattern).

```
return Scaffold(
  body: BlocBuilder<LocationBloc, LocationState>(builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is NewLocationState) {
      return Map(
        location: LatLng(state.latitude, state.longitude),
      );
    }
    return Container();
  }),
);
```

So in code above, the `NewLocationState` comes every 15 sec with new values.

My question is: What is happening with this `Map` Widget?

Does Flutter renders a completely new `Map` Widget every 15sec with new `NewLocationState` or similar to React, Flutter can compare the changes in some kind of virtual tree and only change the properties in an existing `Map` which is efficient and should cause less memory consumption.

Bloc example is just for reference/context of my question. but I want to know overall how Flutter Widget behaves when properties change.

Cheers

Comment: For a complete reference on how the flutter renders the widgets refer to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So in code above, the NewLocationState comes every 15 sec with new values.
>
> Does Flutter renders a completely new Map Widget every 15sec?

Yes. Widgets are aren't reused in any way.

On the other hand, while the widget instance is recreated, its associated `State` & `Element` & `RenderObjects` are preserved (as they are mutable instead).

Since it's these three that does all the work in a Flutter app, it is actually pretty efficient.

Comment: Thanks, so better practice should be instanciate `Map` Widget once without state assertion and move BlocProvider inside `Map` widget or it doesn't matter as this way I'll call setState on `NewLocationState` inside Widget and Widget will rerender anyway?

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: @RémiRousselet well I have a doubt. As you said, Widgets aren't reused, so when the update occurs what happens to the old widget. Does Flutter dispose it or it will be still on the memory ?